# Creating a modal instance on the attribute update of another in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm building a Rails app that has modals `Outage`, `Service`, `Note` and `User`.

`Service` has a boolean attribute `is_down`. By default, `is_down` is `false`. When the attribute is updated to `true` meaning the service goes down, an `Outage` should be created and a `Note` should also be created with `User`, `automated`.

This all happens in one update of the `is_down` attribute. If `Service` goes back up, the outage remains intact but now has an `end_time`.

Here is the 'story line`:

Service model:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :outages 
    has_many :notes


    # This is where I'm confused 
    is_down 
        if self.is_down 
            Outage.create(start_time: Time.now, reason: nil)
            Note.create(user_id: 1, entry: "Outage began at #{Time.now}", service_id: self.id)
        end
    end 
end
```

Outage model:

```
class Outage < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :service
    has_many :notes 
    has_many :users, through: :notes

end
```

Note modal (a join table between `Outage` and `User`)

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :outage
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :notes
    has_many :outages, through: :notes
end
```

`Outage` is more like a story line where during the outage, users can enter notes about what they've learned.

Here is the schema:

```
 enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "entry"
    t.boolean "is_public", default: true
    t.bigint "outage_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["outage_id"], name: "index_notes_on_outage_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_notes_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "outages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.text "reason"
    t.boolean "is_recurring", default: false
    t.string "frequency", default: "None"
    t.bigint "service_id"
    t.index ["service_id"], name: "index_outages_on_service_id"
  end

  create_table "services", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "is_down", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "notes", "outages"
  add_foreign_key "notes", "users"
  add_foreign_key "outages", "services"
end
```

Besides the initial question of automated creation on update of `Service` attribute, `is_down`, is this also a good way to go about implementing this?

Comment: I would consider querying outrages for any non-resolved issues instead of having a boolean switch. It depends on the domain but absolutes are rarely compatible with reality.

Comment: I'm a little confused what the actual question is here. Are you wanting to know if doing it this way is a good idea or not?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps I should create a separate post? I'm a junior developer and the only one who knows rails at my company. Looking for some guidance.

Comment: @max Would you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: Well if you're looking at something like an outrage on an actual physical network it's not actually always that the system is actually up or down. It could just be running slowly or dropping connections.

Comment: So would the OOP way be to create a separate model called `Status` and relate that to `Service`? So `Status` can have more complexity if needed rather than tie it to a single attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the lifecycle callbacks for ActiveRecord. You can add an `after_save` callback to your `Service` class that checks to see if `is_down` has changed and then create or close an `Outage`

```rb
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :outages
  ...

  after_save :create_or_update_outage, if: is_down_changed?

  ...

  private

  def create_or_update_outage
    if is_down
      outages.create
    else
      outages.where(end_time: nil).last.update(end_time: Time.now)
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks good but wasn't able to get it working. I modified it but still not creating an Outage. 


`class Service < ApplicationRecord`
    `has_many :outages` 
    `has_many :notes`
 

   `after_update :create_or_update_outage`

   `private `


  `def create_or_update_outage`
   ` if is_down`
      `Outage.create!("Service = ?", self)`
    `else`
      `Outage.where("Service = ? AND end_time = ?", !self, nil).last.update(end_time:` `Time.now)`
    `end`
  `end`
`end`

Comment: I'm 'byebugging' my way through this and almost have it working now. Reverted back to your code.

Comment: I can get the private method working from a byebug but not without??

Comment: Ok I finally got it working without the proc `if: is_down_changed?`

Comment: @DemianSims I think that's important because you don't want to create or update an Outage unless that value changed. You could move the check to the `create_or_update_outage` method but you need to be sure that the value changed in the last save event.